# Why can't you write "(::) 1 [2]" the way you can write "(+) 1 2" in F#?

Tags: f#

Put an F# infix operator in brackets, and it behaves like a function,

```fsharp
let foo = (*) 3 2  // foo = 6
let factorial n = [2..n] |> List.fold (*) 1  // n!
```

However, this doesn't work with the :: operator (cons operator),

```
let ls = (::) 1 [2..5]  // Error: Unexpected symbol '::' in binding.
```

What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `(::)` (and `[]` for that matter) is a symbolic keyword, you can't expect to use it as an infix operator. See [F# specification](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf), section 3.6 Symbolic keywords.

In this case, you have to define an extra function e.g.

```
let cons x xs = x :: xs
let ls = cons 1 [2..5]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the static method:

```
let ls = List.Cons (1, [2..5])
```

or the operator's verbose name:

```
let ls = op_ColonColon (1, [2..5])
```

(checked with F# 3.0; older versions may behave differently. For instance, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) suggests `op_Cons`)

In both cases, there's no way to curry the arguments here. Numeric operators are defined like this:

```
let inline ( * ) (x:int) (y:int) = ...
```

The list concatenation, however, requires a tuple, and this also answers your question,

> What's the reason for this?

In fact, `(::)` is not an usual operator (a standalone function or a type member), but a **union case**. Here's how the `List<'T>` is defined in [F# sources](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs):

```
type List<'T> =
    | ([])  : 'T list
    | (::)  : Head: 'T * Tail: 'T list -> 'T list
```

So, if your purpose is partial application of arguments, the only *nice* solution would be writing a wrapper function as @pad has suggested.

Comment: very good point - but the problem is not only the union case (you can use your own *constructors* in that way - the problem is we don't get a curried version of these constructors and to make (::) behave as one there seems to be special syntactic suggar in place (indeed you may not even use this kind of definition (a bit like GADTs ;) ) outside the F# library